# Multiple characters in a switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

just to clarify this is hw.

In a project we're doing, a user isn't allowed to enter numbers or special characters (i.e ! @ £ etc)

```
        char letter;
        String phonetic;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Please enter a letter: ");
        letter = letter = kb.next().charAt(0);

        switch(Character.toUpperCase(letter))
{
       case 'A':
            {
                Dot();
                Dash();
                Red();
            }
            break;

        case '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0':
            {
               System.out.println('No number input please!');
            }
        break;
}
```

The error is on

```
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0'
```

Eclipse says

```
invalid character constant
```

Isn't it really long winded if I have to enter all the numbers manually?

i.e. case '1':  case '2':

even with

```
case 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0:
```

It won't work.

Is there an shorter way to do this using switch statements?

Thank you!

Comment: Using switch? No. But there is `Character.isDigit()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because Case expression should be an `int-compatible literal` or a `String` from **java 7**.

```
case '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0':
```

character literals are represented using single quotes. `c`, it should only be of one length, while your case doesn't reflect that, thus the error.

```
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0'  this is not a legal character.
```

If you just wanna check if the character is only alpha, then use [**Charcter#isDigit(char)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) or [**Charcter#isLetter**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) before the switch starts like in below code:

```
char ch=  (Character.toUpperCase(letter);
if(!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
    switch(Character.toUpperCase(letter))
     {
       case 'A':
            {
                Dot();
                Dash();
                Red();
            }
            break;
        }
     }
else {
       System.out.println("no numbers please")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no easier way using case, what about?:

```
if ('0' <= letter && letter <= '9')
  System.out.println('No number input please!');
```

Comment: It's usually because of a `break` or `return` somewhere there shouldn't be one. Note that you can't just replace the `case` inside the `switch` with an `if`, it'll need to be outside the `switch` or in the `default`.

Answer (score 1):

No, Java in this situation is not smart like C#. You need to write multiple lines for that. If you want to compare strings you need to use `if` statements. Also remember to use this code for comparision:

```
if("search".equals(string2)) {...}
```

You cannot compare by `==` this would only compare the memory addresses. Also note that I use the equals on the static string and not on the variable `string2` because you code would break if `string2` is null.

Comment: I refrained from upvoting because I had a hard time understanding what you wrote because of poor language/grammar/spelling. Comparing java to c# is not really relevant. Also, I do not find your if statement and what follows that helpful.

Comment: @ColinD thank you for your feedback. I'm no native speaker so I have sometimes trouble to write *perfect* english. I'm compairing Java to C# because I use both languages and I hate the way how *switch case* works in Java. I love android programming so I use it daily. But I miss the properties from .net.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it really long winded if I have to enter all the numbers manually?

Yes.

> Is there an shorter way to do this using switch statements?

No.

Consider an `if` statement instead...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one enlighten you more.

Consider, your expression generates output as `A , B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, ...till Z`. and you want to execute same method/function for all them.

Then, you can check the `ascii` values of the characters and modify your code to use `if` and `for` loop or else use `switch` as mentioned in the program in following example program.

Play around with code to learn more.

```
public class SwitchClass 
{   

public void method1()
{
        System.out.println("Menthod 1");
}

public void method2()
{
        System.out.println("Menthod 2");
}

public void method3()
{
        System.out.println("Menthod 3");
}   

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    SwitchClass sw = new SwitchClass();
    System.out.println("Enter the String:");
    String input = in.next();

    for(int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++)
    {

        switch(Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i)))
        {

            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
            case 'U':
                    System.out.println(Character.toUppercase(input.charAt(i))+" Case calling");
                    sw.method1();
                    sw.method2();
                    sw.method3();
                    break;

            default:
                    System.out.println("No number input please!");
                    break;
        }
    }       
}
}
```